# How to make variable be taken into account

Tags: shell-script, awk, variable

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'NR!~/^(1|$q+2|$q+3)$/' deltay.txt > yota.txt
```

`q` is an integer obtain from a previous process in the script, and I need to erase lines one, the q+2 an q+3, but that command just erases lines 1... 
How to do it?
PS: I've tried with `sed -e`, but seems I don't own that command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -vq="$q" 'NR>1&&NR!=q+2&&NR!=q+3' deltay.txt > yota.txt
```